# Authorized.net "Sorry, but something went wrong. Please contact the seller."

Tags: checkout, payment, authorize.net, credit-card

I have tried to do `checkout` with `credit card` but this error occurs when placing an order I filled the system config and added the Signature Key other details use both the url sandbox and product I also tried test mode yes/no and also increase time 45 to 60 but issue remains same. I am very tired please anyone give me the solution.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Did you updated the Gateway Url and Payment Update URL correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a recent update.

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024368392

Hope that help you!

Comment: i fixed thanks for reply